# How to refactor this java code

Tags: java, refactoring

I have the below java method called `solution`, there are two large for loops, as you can see, the two for loops are very samilar, so I think it's possible to refactor the code by having a method like `public int getElementSize(ArrayList<Integer> factor1, ArrayList<Integer> factor2)` which does the work of the for loop, so I can just call the method twice with different parameters instead repeating the two for loop. But since these two for loops have different loop orders, one from head to tail, another one from tail to head, beside this, all other parts of the loop are the same, any ideas how to refactor this code?

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        ArrayList<Integer> factor1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> factor2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int factor = 1;
        int N = A.length;
        while(factor * factor <= N){
            if(N % factor == 0){
                factor1.add(factor);
                factor2.add(N / factor);
            }
            factor++;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < factor2.size(); i++){
            int blockSize = factor2.get(i);
            int elementSize = factor1.get(i);
            int peaks = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++){
                boolean hasPeak = false;
                for(int k = elementSize * j; k < elementSize * (j + 1); k++){
                    if(k > 0 && k < N - 1){
                        if(A[k] > A[k - 1] && A[k] > A[k + 1])
                            hasPeak = true;
                    }    
                } 
                if(!hasPeak)
                   break; 
                else
                   peaks++;
            }
            if(peaks == blockSize)
                return blockSize;
        }

        for(int i = factor1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            int blockSize = factor1.get(i);
            int elementSize = factor2.get(i);
            int peaks = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++){
                boolean hasPeak = false;
                for(int k = elementSize * j; k < elementSize * (j + 1); k++){
                    if(k > 0 && k < N - 1){
                        if(A[k] > A[k - 1] && A[k] > A[k + 1])
                            hasPeak = true;
                    }    
                } 
                if(!hasPeak)
                   break; 
                else
                   peaks++;
            }
            if(peaks == blockSize)
                return blockSize;    
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a review of working code. Perhaps it would be more suited to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor the code inside the the for loops to the new method inside move the two big for loops to the new method, in this way, the order of the two loops are still independent, basically it looks like below, the correctness needs to be verified, this is just one idea to not repeat:

```
    class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        ArrayList<Integer> factor1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> factor2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();       
        int factor = 1;
        int N = A.length;
        while(factor * factor <= N){
            if(N % factor == 0){
                factor1.add(factor);
                factor2.add(N / factor);
            }
            factor++;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < factor2.size(); i++){
            int blockSize = factor2.get(i);
            int elementSize = factor1.get(i);
            int peaks = getElementSize(A, blockSize, elementSize); //call the method
            if(peaks == blockSize)
                return blockSize;
        }

        for(int i = factor1.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            int blockSize = factor1.get(i);
            int elementSize = factor2.get(i);
            int peaks = getElementSize(A, blockSize, elementSize); //call the method
            if(peaks == blockSize)
                return blockSize;    
        }

        return 0;
    }

    //this method include the code which was repeated inside the loops 
    public int getElementSize(int[] A, int blockSize, int elementSize){
        int peaks = 0;
        int N = A.length;
        for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++){
            boolean hasPeak = false;
            for(int k = elementSize * j; k < elementSize * (j + 1); k++){
                if(k > 0 && k < N - 1){
                    if(A[k] > A[k - 1] && A[k] > A[k + 1])
                        hasPeak = true;
                }    
            } 
            if(!hasPeak)
                break; 
            else
                peaks++;
        }

        return peaks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Conditional operator, ? and : similar to, (these are called ternary operators and resolve at compile time to if else blocks)

```
if(condition) {
this();
} else { 
that();
}
```

In the above, you can single line that as, (condition ? this() : that())

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    ArrayList<Integer> factor1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> factor2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int factor = 1;
    int N = A.length;
    while(factor * factor <= N){
        if(N % factor == 0){
            factor1.add(factor);
            factor2.add(N / factor);
        }
        factor++;
    }
    // let i = 0 to be factor2, i = 1 is factor 1
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    for(int x = (i == 0 ? 1 : factor1.size() - 1); (i == 0 ? x < factor2.size() : x >= 0); (i == 0 ? x++ : x--)){
        int blockSize = (i == 0 ? factor2.get(x) : factor1.get(x));
        int elementSize = (i == 0 ? factor1.get(x) : factor2.get(x));
        int peaks = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++){
            boolean hasPeak = false;
            for(int k = elementSize * j; k < elementSize * (j + 1); k++){
                if(k > 0 && k < N - 1){
                    if(A[k] > A[k - 1] && A[k] > A[k + 1])
                        hasPeak = true;
                }    
            } 
            if(!hasPeak)
               break; 
            else
               peaks++;
        }
        if(peaks == blockSize)
            return blockSize;
            }
        }

    return 0;
    }
}
```